# Target element in script tag with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Can anyone help me extract the authors name from this script tag using Nokogiri.

I can so far get to the script tag using:

parsed_page.xpath("//script[@type ='application/ld+json']")

I am trying to get the name "Kevin McCart"

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org","@type":"NewsArticle","headline":"OLYMPICS: Check out schedule","url":"https:\/\/www.website.ie\/sport\/winter-olympics-check-out-jack-gowers-schedule-4237649","mainEntityOfPage":{"@type":"WebPage","@id":"https:\/\/www.southernstar.ie\/sport\/winter-olympics-check-out-jack-gowers-schedule-4237649"},"dateCreated":"2022-02-04T12:00:40+00:00","datePublished":"2022-02-04T12:00:40+00:00","dateModified":"2022-02-02T15:08:29+00:00","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/images.website.ie\/uploads\/2022\/01\/24153939\/Jack-Gower-cropped.jpg","image":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https:\/\/images.website.ie\/uploads\/2022\/01\/24153939\/Jack-Gower-cropped.jpg","width":700,"height":370},"articleSection":"Sport","keywords":"Jack Go","author":[{"@type":"Person","name":"Kevin McCart"}],"publisher":{"@type":"Organization","name":"The Southern Star","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject"}}}</script>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Gerard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get to the script tag, nokogiri's work is done, and it's time to parse JSON.

```
require 'json'
def get_kevin(script_element)
  data = JSON.parse(script_element.text)
  data.fetch("author").first.fetch("name")
end
```

Comment: That did the trick Jared! Thanks.